# Need 2 values for one select option

Tags: php, html

Basically I need to make "Select option" from input:

```
<input type="text" name="value[min]" value="0">
<input type="text" name="value[max]" value="100">
```

to something like that:

```
<select name="value[min|max]">
  <option value="0|100">0-100 value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why do you insist on an exact "name" ? How do you receive data when submitted?

Comment: I'm creating e-shop and there should be filter that set price range (like 5$-10$), sadly it can't be done with slider because of customer...

Comment: OK. there is no need to use specific name. You may handle posted data by  server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are taking a single value from the option, no need to make things complex by trying to get the `min`and `max` value this way.

Instead just get the value on server side and format it for your need.

I would have done it this way:

```
<select name="value">
  <option value="0|100">0-100 value</option>
</select>
```

And on server side:

```
<?php
$value = explode('|', $_POST['value']);
$min = $value[0];
$max = $value[1];
```